# Applying sine/cosine rule in non right triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Given: △AKM, KD ⊥ AM,
       AK = 6, KM = 10, m∠AKM = 93º
       Find: KD

By applying first cosine, then sine rule I was able to find KD=~5.03
Can you confirm if this answer is correct? I repeated several times and got the same result. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\frac{1}{2}\cdot |AK|\cdot |KM| \cdot \sin(\angle AKM) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot |AM|\cdot |KD|\\
|KD| = \frac{|AK| \cdot |KM| \cdot \sin(\angle AKM)}{|AM|}\\
|AM| = \sqrt{|AK|^2+|KM|^2-2\cdot |AK| \cdot |KM| \cdot \cos(\angle AKM)}\\
\therefore\space, |KD| = \frac{|AK| \cdot |KM| \cdot \sin(\angle AKM)}{\sqrt{|AK|^2+|KM|^2-2\cdot |AK| \cdot |KM| \cdot \cos(\angle AKM)}}\\ \space \\
$$
Substituting the respective values, we get $5.023$, to 3 decimal places.

Answer (score 3):

$Area=$ $\;$$\dfrac{1}{2}|AK||KM|sin∠AKM=\dfrac{1}{2}|AM||KD|$   $$\\$$  $|AK|$,$\;$ $|KM|$ are given. Also by The Law of Cosines, you can find $|AM|$, thus you can find $|KD|$.

Comment: Hi Taha, I did not start off  with the area. I applied cosine + sine rule based on angles and sides, and got KD=~5.03. Is this correct? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is also correct. You can find $|AM|$ with cosine rule, it gives you $sin∠KAM$ then applying sine rule gives you $|KD|$